# How to create placeholder of listview.

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hello I am looking for easy and simple answer of the list view placeholder. How to create these kind of placeholder in android.

[image: Please check this image]

Please suggest me what will be good way to create like that. I will be thank full to that guy who gonna give me answer of that.